# Java Declaration

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. i know only core java.

I saw the declaration

```
ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> mAppInfo;
```

in Android sample project.
Can anyone explain what is the meaning of above declaration.

Comment: ArrayList of ApplicationInfo type

Comment: There's nothing android specific here. It's a class member (presumably) declaration with generic type.

Answer (score 3):

This is core Java as well. Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html

Also, it should most probably be:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> mAppInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an ArrayList (a container type) which can hold objects of the ApplicationInfo type.

Answer (score 1):

`mAppInfo` is an `ArrayList` of `ApplicationInfo`.  (This list contains only `ApplicationInfo` objects.

It use a *generic* syntax to declare a reference `mAppInfo`.  The name inside the angle bracket is a class name.  For example, we can declare `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a Class from Java collection framework. You can use it in some ways like arrays but there are more advantages compared to normal arrays.

ApplicationInfo is the type of information you allowed to store in this arrayList. (Could also be String Integer, ... just no primitive Datatyps like int, float, ...)

mAppInfo is the name of the ArrayList.

Link to Java Oracle Documentation for more Information on ArrayLists:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Good Luck with your work!